# Open DispForm.aspx will redirect to corresponding sub site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, dispform

I have a list called "Classes".

When a user adds new item, it also creates a site in "Classes" sub site (using custom solution created in VS) as follows:

```
http://myserver/sites/Classes/Class1
http://myserver/sites/Classes/Class2
http://myserver/sites/Classes/Class3
```

So every time I add a new item in that list, it will create related site.

Problem is when user clicks on any item in list, it redirects to corresponding sub site. So let's say if I try to open `http://myservers/Lists/Classes?DispForm.aspx?ID=1` then it will redirect to `http://myserver/sites/Classes/Class1`

Similarly opend DispForm.aspx?ID=2 will redirect to Class2. Normally when you open this page it shows you item detail but here it is happening differently.

This site and code was written by another developer. My question is how do I found out through which code it is redirecting?

I mean I want to know which piece of code is causing this behaviour. I opened DispForm.aspx in SPD but didn't notice anything usual.

Or may be it is some kind of event receiver!?

Can you tell me how to find that code?

Comment: click on edit page and check if there are any web parts added.

Comment: Also check under Site contents -> Site Assets, if there is any js file.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It's a user control that is redirecting to subsite.